# SQLite flush on disk to calc db file hash,how?

Tags: sqlite, hash

I have program which with some period insert row in sqlite database. I need calc hash sum of database file after each insert without close connection. I have some problem with that, after insert database file hash sum are same with they have before insert. Only after closing connection hash sum are changed. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have an open transaction at the point when you're trying to compute the hash? What platform are you running on?

Comment: platform are windows, and i dont have open transaction, just default opened sqlite db file and simple insert, if i do COMMIT after INSERT query i have exception "you dont have open transaction"